# How to architect systems is Enity Component System, in C++

Tags: c++, entity-system, component-based

When creating an ECS in C++, what are good, simple approaches to architecting the systems.

Should each system be a static function of a dedicated class (is this semantically different than just being a global function?) Or maybe the systems should be static methods of a related component or "systems manager"?

Or is there some more elegant way? (neither of these approaches seem elegant to me...)

Comment: My advice: try something, look at what's gone wrong, and improve during your next project. Also, I'd try and avoid using static stuff as much as possible.